# xml schema for collection of same type

Tags: xml, xsd

What is the simplest schema for the following instance :

```
<blocks>
  <block id="1" current="true">ecf1923</block>
  <block id="2">acb79e1</block>
  <block id="3">223a431</block>
</blocks>
```

?

EDIT : This is as far I went...

```
<xs:schema>
      <xs:complexType name="BlockType">
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="current" type="xs:boolean" use="optional"/>
      </xs:complexType>

      <xs:complexType name="BlockCollection">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="block" type="BlockType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>

      <xs:element name="blocks" type="BlockCollection"/>
</xs:schema>
```

I'm just curious if there is a simpler way to achieve the same effect.

Comment: What you want to make simple ^^ this is already simple...

Comment: Define "simple" and "schema" please. If you want someone to right XSD for you then this is the [wrong place](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): show us your current attempt and then ask questions about that.

Comment: You mean, simpler than `<xsd:element name="blocks"/>`?  Or more informative than such a near-vacuous schema, but still 'simple'?

Answer (score 1):

It is very relative what "the simplest" means.

It could be following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="blocks">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="block" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="current" type="xs:boolean"/>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Might be you need define it in that way to be able to reuse some types in other parts of schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="blocks" type="blocks_type"/>
    <xs:complexType name="blocks_type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="block" type="block_type" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="block_type">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="current" type="xs:boolean"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

But you also could need to restrict content of "block" element, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="blocks" type="blocks_type"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="block_content_type">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9a-f]{7}" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="blocks_type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="block" type="block_type" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="block_type">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="block_content_type">
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="current" type="xs:boolean"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And you also could have a requirement to have "id" attribute as key (and therefore unique too):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="blocks" type="blocks_type">
        <xs:key name="id_key">
            <xs:selector xpath="block" />
            <xs:field xpath="@id" />
        </xs:key>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="block_content_type">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9a-f]{7}" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="blocks_type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="block" type="block_type" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="block_type">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="block_content_type">
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="current" type="xs:boolean"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Etc. etc.

The more information about your request you providi the more concrete answer you obtain.